# prettyPhoto with one gallery of more than 100 images

Tags: image, loops, prettyphoto

everyone. I am very new to prettyPhoto. So, I have more than 100 images, and I want to create a gallery of it. Of course, I can add the images one by one, but it is too troublesome. Life could be much more beautiful if I could code it more easily, using something like " for " loop in C or java. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please post the code you're using for a single image.

Comment: <html>
<head><script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<title>
NewSlideshow
</title> <style> .image {display: none;}</style>
</head>
<body  >
<center><div class= "image">
<a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"  href="photo-new\p1.jpg" >
      <img  src="photo-new\p1.jpg" />
  </a>   </center>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
               $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto( {social_tools:'',     slideshow:5000, autoplay_slideshow:true          }     );
api_images = [
'photo-new/p1.jpg'];
$.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,'','');});
 </script></body></html>